# Load Template file With Custom Block

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

Layout code

```
<reference name="content">
            <block type="hello_world/sample" name="world.sample" template="hello/world/simple_page.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

It does not render template file. But It does with `block type="page/html"`

What would be the problem. Is anybody here having solution?

My Block code that is in Hello/World/Block/Sample.php

```
class Hello_World_Block_Sample extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {

    function get_something(){
        return "hai";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code ,your config.xml block code should be

```
<global>
...
<blocks>
    <hello_world> <!- block tye prefix -->
        <class>Hello_World_Block</class>
    <hello_world>
<blocks>
..
</global>
```

Please check.

Comment: Yes @Amit Bera, You are correct.

Comment: You are welcome